# What are the WSO2 tested Operating Systems?

Tags: operating-system, wso2, wso2-esb

I run WSO2 ESB 4.6 on my Windows 8 and on the Windows Server 2012 machine. But on both machine I get one of the following messages:

> WARN - ValidationResultPrinter The running OS : Windows Server 2012 is not a tested Operating System for running WSO2 Carbon
>
> WARN - ValidationResultPrinter The running OS : Windows 8 is not a tested Operating System for running WSO2 Carbon

**What are then the tested WSO2 Carbon OS?**

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, windows 7/ubuntu 11 .X ,12.X.X, RHEL 5.X

Comment: Can you give me the source where you found this information - or where it is documented. Thanks

Comment: You can  check following guide..http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Installation+Prerequisites

Comment: Your link gives a good answer: `Linux/Solaris are recommended for a production deployment.` On the other systems it is just `generally possible to run`...